# MIPS Relative Addressing

Tags: mips

Can somebody please help me answer these three questions?:

Two identified here:
[image: http://s11.postimage.org/lrb0exx5v/Capture2.png]
When we multiply the immediate operand by 4, do we multiply the binary or the decimal by 2^2? Is the addition sign for concatenation?

What is the maximum offset from $s?:
[image: http://s11.postimage.org/emt75wpwj/Capture.png]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Addition sign is for relative addressing not concatenation.
$PC=$PC +I*4; means that program counter will point from itself by I*4 locations.

"What is maximum branch distance?" 
If we look beq or bne instruction, OP, RS, RT, OFFSET = 32bits. For offset is reserved 16bits so the maximum branch distance is 2^16=65535. Sometimes 2^16 is not enough to reach location jump and than you may use unconditional jump.

"What is the maximum offset from $s" I beleive the answer is the same 2^16.

Comment: In MIPS the 16-bits is sign extended (if I recall correctly, the offset is also relative to the next PC--which is the location of the delay slot instruction), so the magnitude of the offset is effectively only 2^15.  Sign extension applies to branches and data accesses. Also as Brian Carlton notes, the branch offset is in 4B instruction words.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for *4 is the instruction counter points to (32-bit) words. Each word is 4 bytes. Multiplying by 4 gives you a bigger range than making the offset a number of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You're question appears to be asking for ranges, but the answer given are for the number possible branch locations. The correct answer to you're question should be as follows:

For the first question, we know BEQ uses PC-Relative addressing which is hopefully self-explanatory. But the important thing to note is how PC will be updated: PC=PC+SE(IR[15-0]::00) as defined on the MIPS Green Sheet. Now obviously, we can rationalize that we must AT LEAST be able to branch to location 2^15 (Because of Sign-Extending) relative to our current PC, but the question is asking for the maximum branch distance that can be achieved. And because we shift left by 2 (multiply by 4 to word-align), we actually have 2 extra bits to play with. However, the two bits are always 00 and cannot be changed so the max branch distance you can achieve is PC+(2^17-4).

For the second question, it is asking for the maximum distance from $s. For LW, we know the address is calculated as Addr=R[rs]+SE(offset), also defined on the MIPS Green Sheet. In this case, we don't shift by 2 because there are operations that load/store other things besides words, such as LH, LB or SH and SB. But, now if the 'offset' is 16-bit signed then automatically we know it can take the range of -(2^15) -> (2^15)-1 and because it will be relative distance from $s, we can take the larger of the magnitudes. So the greatest offset relative to $s will be 2^15.